# Filter an PHP Array and consider the date range

Tags: php, arrays, date, filter, merge

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-01-10        
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-01-11
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-01-12
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-01-15
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-01-18
    )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-01-19
    )
)
```

And I want to combine the dates by his ranges. At the end I need something like the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [from] => 2012-01-10
        [till] => 2012-01-12
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [from] => 2012-01-15
        [till] => 2012-01-15
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [from] => 2012-01-18
        [till] => 2012-01-19
    )
)
```

But it should also support a wide range. Something like 2012-01-22 till 2012-05-14. Anyone an idea or an hint?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If you provide what you've tried, it might be faster to point out improvements to that rather than creating a solution for you from scratch. (FYI, some people get grumpy when you don't show your attempt because it looks like you're just asking others to do your work. :-)

Answer (score 0):

your output does not contain the same dates as your input in the example above. how are the from/till dates decided? do we simply go through the array and alternate between from to?

```
function from_till($dates = array()){
  $sorted = array();
  for($i=0; $i<count($dates)-2; $i+=2){
    $sorted[] = array('from' => $dates[$i], 'till' => $dates[$i+1];
  }
  return $sorted;
}
```

input:

```
$input = Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-01-10        
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-01-11
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-01-12
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-01-15
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-01-18
    )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-01-19
    )
);
```

output:

```
  $output = from_till($input);
  print_r($output);
```

output of print_r

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [from] => 2012-01-10
        [till] => 2012-01-11
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [from] => 2012-01-12
        [till] => 2012-01-15
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [from] => 2012-01-18
        [till] => 2012-01-19
    )
);
```